# Facebook app - getting AuthToken

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

I have created a Facebook app using RestFB. In my local environment it is working fine. To put the app on the web, I need to get token. I am following these steps:

1. Redirecting from Facebook to my app url using app id and secret key.
2. Getting code from url
3. Trying to redirect using code to get authtoken

I am not able to complete step 3,  Please help me.

A sample code will be most appreciated.

Comment: Did my answer helped you or not?

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed this step exactly ?

```
Create a Facebook Application
Request https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=MY_API_KEY& redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html& scope=publish_stream,create_event
Facebook will redirect you to http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html? code=MY_VERIFICATION_CODE
Request https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=MY_API_KEY& redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html& client_secret=MY_APP_SECRET&code=MY_VERIFICATION_CODE
Facebook will respond with access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Answer (score 0):

Get your APP_ID/Key and APP_SECRET
use the below code

```
AccessToken accessToken = new DefaultFacebookClient().obtainAppAccessToken(APP_ID, APP_SECRET);
DefaultFacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken.getAccessToken());
```

Struggled long time to find this simple method.